# Notify of dynamic ip address changes?

Tags: networking, router, ip, dynamic-dns

I have full remote access to a router however from time to time the ip address changes and thus I lose my ability to connect remotely because I no longer know the ip address.

So I want to be notified of any time the ip address is changed, what is the best way to approach this?

Note: there aren't any machines connected to the router that I can write scripts on.

Comment: This is literally why Dynamic DNS exists.

Comment: @acejavelin is it possible to disable it? If so are there security implications?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean... You create a DDNS for your location  "location.dynamic-dns.com" or something like that, depends what your router supports or you can run an application on a device inside the LAN to update it. Then no matter what your IP address becomes, the DDNS name entry points to that IP. You don't need to be notified as it doesn't matter because you use the name instead of the IP address. Some paid DDNS providers will email you if the address changes, but I don't know of any free ones that do. I am sure you could do this with a simple bash script though.

Comment: Oh I understand your original comment now. Excuse me. Can I use create a dynamic dns myself or do I have to use a service provider? Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your ISP changes your IP periodically.

As one solution, you could ask the ISP for a static IP address that
never changes. Quite often this is a paid option.

An alternate solution is using
[Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS),
to refer to your computer by using a domain-name, rather than IP address.

Dynamic DNS providers exist, and you may find such a list in the above
Wikipedia article. Some of them are free for personal use.

Many routers support Dynamic DNS and will automatically notify your
Dynamic DNS supplier about an IP change.

Otherwise, some Dynamic DNS providers supply software running on your computer
that will do the updating for you. An example is the free
[DYNU](https://www.dynu.com/en-US).

Comment: Thanks. Are there any security implications for asking the ISP for a static ip that never changes?

Comment: Only that that you will always be found in the same address, and too bad if the static address that the ISP allocated was previously used by a hacker and will be rejected by some websites. Anecdote: I use non-static IP myself, and when this happened to me (although very *very* rarely) I had to wait 24 hours for the IP to change again.

Comment: @ZD Static IP Adresses don't allow for private browsing (unless you use a VPN, proxy etc.) other then that it won't matter much. Be aware that you can easily change a dyndns subdomain, if a static IP address you can always be reached through this IP (makes continuous attacks a bit easier). I never heard of a hacker using an IP from a static ip range, it's more likely that a hacker compromises your system and uses your IP for attacks then your IP gets blocked and you need to get active to get it unblocked from various black list (which is a pain in the ass).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have machines you can install a service on, either, this won't help, but...

There may be better ways, and I may get some minimal notifications for when I solely get my IP changed, but not my WAN, but [IP Monitor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ipmonitor/) looks like it'll do the job for me for free.  I have it set to give screen notifications plus send an email, but you can also have it make a sound.  You can configure rolling logs in it, and also install it as a service as well.  My Asus Merlin firmware frequently (or never?) fails back for some reason.
There is also Home Assistant and [this](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/setting-up-dual-secondary-wan-notification-for-asus-routers/175626), but I don't use it (yet).

Edit:  Note that this solution requires Java to be installed.